# EXTERNAL-IP is <none> in Kubernetes service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, dask, dask-distributed

I followed [these instructions](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/kubernetes-helm.html#helm-install-dask-for-a-single-user) to deploy a Dask cluster on Kubernetes/Minikube with Helm. I installed and the deployed with the following command:

```
 helm install dask-chart dask/dask
```

Running `kubectl get services` I see the scheduler, however the EXTERNAL-IP is `none` and I cannot connect to the scheduler:

```
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
dask-chart-scheduler   ClusterIP   10.107.222.251   <none>        8786/TCP,80/TCP   36m
```

What could be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

It's not only Dask, all the services have EXTERNAL-IP = none. I restarted Minikube but same problem persists.

Comment: Run minikube tunnel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected behavior if you use the service as `ClusterIP`. The meaning of `ClusterIP` is to let the service be accessible within the cluster. You should refer to this section from the official doc about the definition of `ClusterIP`, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types.

If you want to use the tunnel, you need to first set the service as `LoadBalancer`. Inside the minikube documentation, you can check out the full tutorial how you can access the apps inside the cluster, https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel.

Comment: For those that deploy the dask distributed gateway, what was missing in my case was to do a port fordwarding of the service, external IP is not used